# EclipseLink and hibernate learning

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I'm reading now Beginning "Java™ EE 6 Platform with GlassFish™" book, the book talk about JPA and uses  EclipseLink 1.1 as implementation of JPA, after than I heard that hibernate is most powerful and used by almost now.

are EclipseLink and hibernate are just implementation and the user of JPA can use anyone of them using the same annotations?
If I want to learn hibernate, is JPA with EclipseLink from that book enough? or they are quite different?

Comment: There are many JPA implementations, not just the ones you have heard of in some very restricted world. DataNucleus JPA and OpenJPA are two more that have significant usage

Answer (score 0):

Eclipselink and hibernate do the same work when it comes to java persistence. Both have there own ways of configuration although similar to a large extent. Both support annotation based and xml based mapping.
Eclipselink version 1.1 would be really outdated. The latest one is 2.4. something. Since both hibernate and EclipseLink are implementation to JPA specification, the jpa annotations like javax.persistence. would work , should work in exact same way for both. But their are also properties and annotations which are specific to hibernate and eclipselink, for example the database connection properties.

If you want to learn hibernate, I am sure you can find lots of online material and hard copies specific to hibernate.

Comment: My question is about my time I spent on the book that explains the JPA using eclipseLink, can you please take a look on the book Chapter{3,4,5,6} and tell me if I these chapters in general have any specifications that can't be used by hibernate?

Comment: and sure not in terms of configurations that definitely different like hibernate.cfg and persidence.xml, I mean in terms of annotations and their semantic.